# How to make background process which always run and do scheduled task in Grails?

Tags: grails, background-process

I have new requirement today.I have to build a background process which can run continuously and do task such as database manipulation in `grails`server side.I have a task , and I have to check that if this task is running from last 6 hours or more then I have to make it off using this background process.May `grails plugin` offer this functionality? Or I have to do something from scripts and run it with other services continuously.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use grails plugins, you may consider [Quartz](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz), [Quartz2](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz2) or [BackgroundThread](http://grails.org/plugin/background-thread) plugin. The Quartz2 plugin is newer and provide the functionality you want.

Comment: is there any way to do with script file ?

Comment: I have created a a test.groovy file in `\script` directory and manually running it using ` run-script scripts/test.groovy` command.This is executing very well.But what I want to do is how should I call this script continuously?I am creating a `war` file from my `grails` app and deploy it on server , now I want to call this script while server is running not by using command manually .How could I make call to this script file so I can done my script task continuously? Thanks.

Comment: Plugins are created to hide the complexities and help increase production rate, You should use the plugins instead of trapping yourself in your own scripts. The above plugins do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.But I want to run script file without using command line.can you please help.

Comment: you will not need to use command line, just go through the plugins' links, you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Using a quartz plugin ..... [[www.grails.org/plugin/quartz‎]](http://www.grails.org/plugin/quartz%E2%80%8E)

## Scheduling a Cron Job

```
class MyJob  {
  static triggers = {
    cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0 6 * * ?"
  }
 def group = "MyGroup"
 def execute(){
   print "Job run!"
 }
}
```

for further reference consult this page http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html